# Hosting Umbraco in a Windows Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I have just upgraded my client's Umbraco installation to v6.0.2 and we want to now migrate it to a 2x node Windows Azure Cloud Service.  I have just finished implementing a new File System Provider by implementing IFileSystem.  I'm now able to use Blob storage for storing media.

However, I have noticed that the URLs to the existing media on the front-end are not updated; they appear to still point to the (now non-existent) ~/media directory. Also, in the Umbraco back-end, whenever I try to insert an image into the tinymce editor, it calls a webservice and errors:

```
/umbraco/controls/Images/ImageViewerUpdater.asmx/UpdateImage
Message=The relative virtual path 'http:/127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/umbraco/1001/favorite-32.png' is not allowed here.
```

Am I right in thinking Umbraco isn't yet ready for load balanced environments like Azure?

I had assumed now with the introduction of IFileSystem that Azure was now supported?  Maybe I have missed something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered, to date, there is no "official" web farm support in Umbraco versions all the way up to v6+ in-spite of the introduction of the new File System Providers / IFileSystem interface.

There's Umbraco "Concorde" in the pipeline which will provision Umbraco as a service; I'm unsure whether this somehow also includes the changes to support Azure as part of our own custom solution deployments.

In the mean time, it's best to use the deprecated, unsupported, Microsoft-developed Umbraco Windows Azure Accelerator available from: https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-accelerator-umbraco

There is anecdotal evidence that this is a robust way to deploy Umbraco into a web farm scenario, such as Windows Azure.

Comment: The old accelerator does work, we've been using it since last July on a production website. It basically just syncs up the local file systems of the azure instances with a location on blob storage.

Comment: There have been a lot of improvements in Umbraco for running on Azure since this question was answered. See https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/azure-web-apps and https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/load-balancing/flexible. Also I would recommend checking out https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/azure-cdn-toolkit-for-umbraco/.

Answer (score 0):

Would the Umbraco installation as part of Windows Azure Web Sites be an option?  Granted it seems like you've already put a lot of work into getting Umbraco going on a Cloud Service.

Comment: The problem with websites is that it's still in preview (no SLA) and it's still only one node, i.e., single point of failure. I need the resilience and availability that a 2x node Cloud Service brings (together with the SLA's 99.9% up-time guarantee).